# Debugging Windows 10 Mobile App on a Device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I created new UWP app in VS2015, but when I am trying to debug App on a device it's giving me below error:

Error : DEP6400 : Failed to deploy. Make sure another deployment or debugging session is not in progress for the same emulator or device from a different instance of Visual Studio: Error writing file '%FOLDERID_SharedData%\PhoneTools\11.0\Debugger\bin\RemoteDebugger\vbdebug.dll'. Error 0x80072736: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

Below is my system spec:
Windows 10 PC Build: 10240,
Visual Studio 2015, UWP SDK: 10586,
Package Manifest Target Version : 10586
Package Manifest Min Version : 10240
Windows 10 Mobile Build on Device: 10.0.10586.71,

Please guide me what this error is and how to resolve this error.

Comment: your phone is there in developer mode?

Comment: Yes, Developer mode is ON.

Answer (score 0):

Zee,

Please make sure that you are checking the following below running the app.

1. There is a chance that you already opened a visual studio and you would have run app. Then you would have opened visual studio again and you tried the run the app again.

Here the problem is, only one visual studio can run at a time. When the first visual studio is running and when you try to launch the project once again, it will fail.

2. Try to restart your machine and run the project.
3. If you are not willing to restart the machine, open your task manager and close all the visual studio running instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I perfomed mentioned step, and now getting below error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Error : DEP2100 : Cannot copy the file "C:\Users\XYZ\.nuget\packages\System.IO.Compression.clrcompression-arm\4.0.0\runtimes\win10-arm\native\ClrCompression.dll" to the target machine "127.0.0.1". 
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8EDE0012 FileThumbnails

Comment: It is saying that System.IO.Compression.clrcompression cannot able to copy into the local folder. Please go to references, and right click that particular dll and select properties and select Copy Local to true.

Comment: Zee, I'm not willing to do this.